# Event Driven Microservice Race Condition

Tags: java, architecture, microservices, eventual-consistency, apache-kafka

Say we have 4 services, A through D, which communicate (for the most part) through some sort of asynchronous event-driven system. When a new entity is created in A, B & C receive that event. B creates an entity of its own based on that event, and C makes a synchronous call to D to perform an action. Finally D receives both A and B's entity and performs the action requested by C which **requires** both A and B's entities.

*Note: A,B, and D are essentially CRUD services which also have REST APIs, while C is business logic and has no state. A, B, and D are intended to be product-agnostic services in a cloud environment.*

This flow works fine when dealing with updating existing entities as service D stores a partial copy of the data it receives from A and B, but it creates a sort of race condition when A creates a new entity. Note that even if A and B have created their entities before C performs the call, there's no guarantee that D has read both events.

What are common ways of dealing with this? I've come up with several, but none of them seem particularly great.

1. Retry Pattern

   - Which entity performs the retry? Since this action needs to eventually be performed, I assume having it in service D is a bad idea as it then can't distinguish from bad input through the REST API, or requires duplicated functionality to differentiate between an event and a REST call.
   - Even if that was acceptable, it pushes business logic into a CRUD service.
2. Webhook between D and B

   - Again, puts the logic into a CRUD service (kinda).
3. Thread sleep on C

   - These anywhere in a running service generally seems like a horrible idea...
   - Doesn't help with the condition where B goes down while the rest stay up.

*Edit in response to answers:*

1. Have C wait for the two Events before it invokes D

   - This unfortunately doesn't guarantee that D has read those same events, even though it is more likely.
   - C can't send the full contents of the event from A with the request, just the ID of the object without duplicating the REST interface methods on D; other services to come won't have anything except the ID when they request D's service(s). In all other cases, all the necessary information will reside in D to perform its service, the awkward case seems to be only for new entities.
2. Have D wait for both create events from A and B and then do the logic without C having to tell it to.

   - This seems to break the single-responsibility principle.
   - A, B, and D are intended to be 'product-agnostic' services, see edit to the note above. The implication is that this would push logic into a service that is used by multiple products, even though the logic is specific to only one product.

Answer (score 2):

Think of your situation as data and processes that depend on it. What results is this:

- Service `A` creates entity `a`
- Service `B` creates entity `b`
- Service `D` performs a process `d` which depends on `a` and `b`
- The decision on when `d` should happen is made by service `C`

`D` has to do its duty when `C` tells it to, but `C` does not provide all dependencies for that process.

---

Thats the problem how i see it. Now on to the solution: If you want to keep `D` as simple as possible, `C` has to provide all necessary information to `D`. There is no way around that.

If it is acceptable to put some logic into `D` (depending on the language and frameworks in use, that logic might happen to be 2 LoC), you can wait for all data in `D`:

1. Entity `a` is created with ID `11`
2. Entity `b` is created with ID `22` and referes to `a#11`
3. `C` listens for the create-event of `b` and then tells `D` the following:
   "As soon as you have `a#11` and `b#22`, do `d` with them.
4. `D` waits for both events and then does its thing.

If you are using tools like Promises and ReactiveX, this becomes a really simple thing:

```
// within C
class EntityEvents
    Observable<EntityCreatedEvent<T>> onCreated(Class<T> entityClass)

entityEvents.onCreated(EntityB.class).subscribe(b -> d.doYourThing(b.aId, b.id));

// within D
class EntityRepository
    Promise<EntityA> getExistingOrOnCreated(long aId)
    Promise<EntityB> getExistingOrOnCreated(long bId)

// within D - when the call "doYourThing" from C is received
Promise.all(
   entityRepository.getExistingOrOnCreated(aId),
   entityRepository.getExistingOrOnCreated(bId)
).then((entityA, entityB) -> {
   // do whatever it is you need to do
})
```

This gets a lot harder when you have to persists the waits for the entities. In that case, a scheduled job may be the better choice.

Comment: Thanks; it looks like I have a couple more details to add to the question that might (or might not) change your answer. See the 'edit'.

Comment: @Asmodean i updated my answer

Answer (score -2):

If D requires Entities from A and B, simply event notifies C only, C is the logic to control the rest of the flow so C calls A, then C calls B, then C calls D.